# How to move border bottom bar to the end of navbar while hovering

Tags: html, css

How can I move the red bottom bar to the end of the navbar on hovering on my list elements? Also, as you can see the edges of the bar are not straight, how can I fix this issue?

[image]

Current code: -

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.6rem 12%;
  background-color: #1c2236;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.nav-links {
  li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2.5px solid transparent;
    margin: 0.4rem 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    &:hover {
      border-bottom: 2.5px solid red;
      padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.25s;
    }
  }
}
a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your sass

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 12%;
  background-color: #1c2236;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.nav-links {
  margin-bottom: 0;

  li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2.5px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.4rem 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;

    &:hover {
      border-bottom: 2.5px solid red;
      padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.25s;
    }
  }
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}
```